# pyinstaller fails with IndexError

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am working on a windows 10 64-bit system.

I have a python script that queries an API with user defined data. Specifically the user enters a couple of search terms, using `input()` method. The data is retrieved in JSON format which I either display on console or save in a text file depending on an option selected by the user.

I want to turn this script into an exe so the user can run this without having to install python. I used `pyinstaller`, but have been unsuccessful so far.

I have an anaconda installation on my system, and I used pip to install `pyinstaller` as suggested in the docs.

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile my_script.py
```

These are the errors I am getting

```
236 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
236 INFO: Python: 3.6.0
236 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0
236 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Keshav\Documents\Hicotronics\rochester_scrape\data_get2.spec
298 INFO: UPX is available.
298 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths ['C:\\Users\\Keshav\\Documents\\Hicotronics\\rochester_scrape',  'C:\\Users\\Keshav\\Documents\\Hicotronics\\rochester_scrape']
298 INFO: checking Analysis
298 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
298 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
314 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
314 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 788, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in build
exec(text, spec_namespace)
File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
self.__postinit__()
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 161, in __postinit__
self.assemble()
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 317, in assemble
excludes=self.excludes, user_hook_dirs=self.hookspath)
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 560, in initialize_modgraph
graph.import_hook(m)
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1509, in import_hook
source_package, target_module_partname, level)
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1661, in _find_head_package
target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 209, in _safe_import_module
module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2077, in _safe_import_module
module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2167, in _load_module
self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2585, in _scan_code
module, module_code_object, is_scanning_imports=False)
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2831, in _scan_bytecode
global_attr_name = get_operation_arg_name()
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2731, in get_operation_arg_name
return module_code_object.co_names[co_names_index]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Please help me debug this, since I have no idea what is causing this to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.6 is not fully supported by PyInstaller for Windows 10.
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2286

Comment: Yes. I resolved this by using conda to create a new environment based on python 3.4. Also some other problems I faced even after switching python versions, was the requests library I was using to get data in my app didn't work well with pyinstaller. So I had to switch to urllib.request in order to get a working executable.